# Accessing PHP variable inside a string stored in variable

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to resolve value for the PHP variable stored as a string in a database field.
I know that using echo with double quotes detects PHP variable and prints it's value. I tried wrapping the value in the database inside {} as well.
But I am not getting the same results from the string stored in a variable ($str2 in this case). $str2 stores a result of a database query.

I am using the Yii2 framework here. Is there any way to do the same in core PHP or in Yii2? I tried Herodoc as well.

Edit: The string stored in $str2 has some HTML tags as well, that is why I cannot use `eval`.

```
$str = 'foo';
$str2 = SomeClass::getValue($someParam); 
    //returns string with variable names in it i.e. '<h1> somestring: $str</h1>' or '<h1> somestring: {$str}</h1>'

echo '{$str}'; //prints $str
echo "{$str}"; // prints foo
echo "{$str2}"; //prints $str or {$str} , why??

echo <<<EOT
"{$str2}"
EOT;   //prints $str or {$str} , why??
```

Comment: Because `$str2` contains either `$str` or `{$str}` what do you expect?

Comment: Just don't use bad practice syntax. Use `echo $str2 . ' - concated';`. Some people might argue that using `{}` or double quotes is not bad practice but they are awully wrong and not used to best practice. Most magic-variable building is considered bad pratice too. Write integral PHP code, not magic PHP code.

Comment: *"using echo with double quotes detects PHP variable and prints it's value"* -- the string enclosed in double quotes is source code. The compiler analyzes it, detects the `{}` blocks and interprets them as references to variables. This does not happen with random strings processed at runtime; they are data, not code and the compiler does not see them.

Answer (score 2):

The variable in string only works when the string is evaluated by PHP processor. So it's only usable in strings in your source code. The string is not evaluated when it comes from other sources like DB or result of expression.

There are two options how you can solve your problem.

**1) Use str_replace to replace variable inside your string**

```php
$stringFromDb = '<p>Some text with {$variable}</p>';
$text = str_replace('{$variable}', $variable, $stringFromDb);
echo $text;
```

This way is better because you can control in your source code what variables can be accessed. Also the string itself is not processed as code.

**2) use `eval()` to evaluate the string (not safe)**

Because your string can contain some other text you need to modify it before evaluating it.

```php
$variable = 'test';
$stringFromDb = '<h1>{$variable}</h1>';

$string = '$text = "' . $stringFromDb . '";';
eval($string);
echo $text;
```

You can only use this approach if you are sure the string from DB cannot contain any malicious code. Because an attacker can use this to run any php code.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options that I see.

Use just the text name of the variable and use a  variable variable:

```
$str = 'foo';
$str2 = 'str'; 
echo $$str2;
//or
echo ${$str2};
//or
echo ${"$str2"};
```

Or evaluate the string inside the variable as a variable:

```
$str = 'foo';
$str2 = '$str'; 
eval("echo $str2;");
```

All output `foo`.

Comment: Thanks for answering @AbraCadaver, my string contains some other characters other than the variable name, such as Html tags(just edited the question details). So using $$ or eval is not working.